# css same class names get same style

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="body">
     text text text
  </div>
  <div class="comment_submit">
       <!-- here goes username text field !-->
       <div class="body">
         <textarea></textarea>
       </div>
       <!-- here goes submit button !-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
#wrapper .body{
  border:1px solid red;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  padding:5px;
}
.comment_submit .body{
  border:2px solid red;
  background:#cccccc;
}
```

Why does body div which is inside comment_submit div gets the **#wrapper .body** style and not only the **.comment_submit .body** style?

i understand that **#wrapper .body** style includes all **.body** divs that are inside #wrapper but how i can stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solves your problem:

```
#wrapper > .body{
  border:1px solid red;
  background:#f5f5f5;
  padding:5px;
}
```

1. `#wrapper .body` = "Select every `.body` which is a descendant of `#wrapper`".
2. `.comment_submit .body` = "Select every `body` class which is a descendant of `.comment_submit`.

ID selectors have a higher specifity than class selectors, so properties which are defined in the first selector take precedence over the ones from #2.

- The solution utilises the child selector, `>`, which says: "Select every `.body` element which is a *direct* child of `#wrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

`#wrapper .body{}` will apply to all `.body` classes no matter how deep they are, as long as they are still within `#wrapper`.

I would recommend renaming the `.body` which is inside the `.comment_submit` to `.comment_submit_body` to fix your problem.

Your class names should not be the same for different styles.

Answer (score 0):

That is related to [Selector Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). Simply it means that #id selector (first case) has priority over class selector (second case). You could fix that by

```
#wrapper .comment_submit .body{
  border:2px solid red;
  background:#cccccc;
}
```